# ColdFusion to PHP: Can I make queries as easily?

Tags: php, sql, coldfusion, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I'm working for a large company that has a ton of ColdFusion web applications.  They're requiring all these apps to transition to new platforms/languages.

One of these applications is quite large and complex. Its target is PHP due to resource familiarity and support.

One of the nice things I liked about ColdFusion was the ability to sort of "free-form" a SQL query between `<cfquery>` tags.  I'm wondering if there's a way to do that in PHP.

Here's an example of a query that I might have embedded in a ColdFusion component (CFC).  What the query does isn't as important as how all parts of the query between `cfquery` tags are conditionally built:

```
<cfquery>
    select nametable.uid, firstname, lastname

    <cfif isdefined('alldata')>
        ,phone
        ,email
    </cfif>

    from
        nametable

    <cfif isdefined('alldata')>
        inner join contactdata
        on nametable.uid=contactdata.uid
    </cfif>

    where 1=1

    <cfif isdefined('firstname')>
        and firstname like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#firstname#">
    </cfif>

    <cfif isdefined('lastname')>
        and firstname like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#lastname#">
    </cfif>

    <cfif isdefined('uidlist')>
        and nametable.uid in <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#uidlist#" list="true">
    </cfif>

    <cfif searchByDate>
        and cast(datafield as date)
    <cfelse>
        and datafield
    </cfif>

    between
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#attrValue1#">
    and
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#attrValue2#">

    <cfif isdefined("attrVals")>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#attrVals.length()#" index="i">
            and dbo.getPersonAttr(nametable.uid,'#attrvals[i].cd()#') = 
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#attrvals[i].val()#">
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>

    order by

    <cfif orderby eq "uid">nametable.uid<cfelse>lastname</cfif>

</cfquery>
```

To me, even though there is a variety of logical paths, that code is:

- very easy to read,
- simple to understand, and
- easy to debug syntactically

Several other features that this dynamically built query has:

- inline if/else logic and looping - across all SQL clauses (Select, joins, where, order by, group, etc.)
- inline, **variable** data binding: there might be 0 bound parameters, or 50+; we won't know or care until runtime
- native data binding for list values (...where uid in ('12345','98765')...) (in coldfusion, `<cfqueryparam ... list="true">`)

I don't think I need a lesson on just how you *can* build a PHP query; I know you can sit there and rather tediously concatenate small strings together to accomplish something similar.

What I'd like to ask is:

1. Is there a way to construct queries in PHP similar to the way they're constructed in ColdFusion, by using the `<cfquery></cfquery>` tags as the boundaries of the buffer, with clean logic and syntax in between, and
2. Regardless of the answer to #1, is there any straightforward way in PHP to perform data binding when the number of bound parameters varies, is not known until runtime, and the number of which might be determined with multi-variable logic?  To do it in the above example is trivial - you simply use `<cfqueryparam>` where and when you need it.

Because we don't have the time or resources to re-architect the entire application, I'm not looking, for example, to map all our objects via ORM.  I really just want to construct queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From my understanding for PHP you can go two paths for querying data from the database, you can choose either PHP MySQLi or PDO. Both are extremely powerful for getting and receiving data from many databases. All it requires is setting up a connection to the database which is extremely simple. You just have to create a dbconnect.php file. And then make another file, require the dbconnect file and simply start writing queries to query information from the database you set up in the dbconnect file you're connecting to. If I had to choose between the two, I would choose PDO.

Comment: FWIW, my last gig, we outlawed all inline queries like this and replaced them with stored procedure. You can accomplish the same conditional search logic and you can transition between programming languages, API, unit testing, etc. much easier.

Comment: SELECTS I can see (and we do use) in some cases. In the example above, in the last part of the WHERE clause, I specifically put in an example where we have 0 to n dynamic attributes to check. Our DBMS does not allow array arguments, nor would I want to write the stored procedure even if we could fudge it with lists, which is a terrible idea to begin with. Also, no way we could use stored procs on INSERTs when we're dealing with complex objects and multi-table inserts (maybe with CRUD, especially if your table structure is relatively static). In short, we use sprocs when possible, but not here.

Comment: If the database engine was sql server, you could use dynamic sql to accomplish the example in the question.  It would not be as easy as doing it with ColdFusion but it might be easier than doing it with php.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, we have a mix of DBMS flavors.  Also, dynamic SQL on MSSQL (as I recall; it's been a while) is generally of the concatenate-tons-of-strings-together-then-execute variety...what I was hoping to avoid in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is using [a query builder in PHP](https://github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder). This would look like this (incomplete example):

```
$columns = [ 'nametable.uid', 'firstname', 'lastname' ];

if isset($alldata) {
    array_push($columns, 'phone', 'email');
}

$builder = new GenericBuilder(); 

$query = $builder
    ->select()
    ->setTable('nametable')
    ->setColumns($columns)
;

if isset($firstname) {
    $query
        ->where()
        ->like('firstname', $firstname)
}

etc.
```

It will take some time to get used to it, but I consider this more readable than the mentioned string concatenation hell.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  We're going to look into one of these builders and try to generate several of our most complex queries with one.  May take some time but will report back.